# C# Request Token 401 Unauthorized access

Tags: c#, api, twitter, oauth

I am trying to generate a `request_token` using the oAuth method as mentioned in the links below:

https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/overview/creating-signatures
https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/reference/post/oauth/request_token

No matter how many times I go through the Twitter API oauth procedure, am failing to make my request work.

I came across this blog with an example on how to go about updating a user timeline.

https://garyshortblog.wordpress.com/2011/02/11/a-twitter-oauth-example-in-c/

Using the same concept I modified it a little to request a token

```
public string signedSignature(string status, string postBody, string oauth_consumer_key, string oauth_nonce, string oauth_signature_method,
                                    string oauth_token, string callbackURL, string oauth_timestamp, string oauth_version)
    {            

        //GS - When building the signature string the params
        //must be in alphabetical order. I can't be bothered
        //with that, get SortedDictionary to do it's thing
        SortedDictionary<string, string> sd =
            new SortedDictionary<string, string>();

        //sd.Add("status", status);
        sd.Add("include_entities", "true");
        sd.Add("oauth_consumer_key", oauth_consumer_key);
        sd.Add("oauth_nonce", oauth_nonce);
        sd.Add("oauth_signature_method", oauth_signature_method);
        sd.Add("oauth_timestamp", oauth_timestamp);
        sd.Add("oauth_token", oauth_token);
        sd.Add("oauth_version", oauth_version);

        //GS - Build the signature string
        string baseString = String.Empty;
        baseString += "POST" + "&";
        baseString += Uri.EscapeDataString(
            "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token")
            + "&";

        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> entry in sd)
        {
            baseString += Uri.EscapeDataString(entry.Key +
                "=" + entry.Value + "&");
        }

        //GS - Remove the trailing ambersand char, remember 
        //it's been urlEncoded so you have to remove the 
        //last 3 chars - %26
        baseString =
            baseString.Substring(0, baseString.Length - 3);

        //GS - Build the signing key
        string consumerSecret =
            "<consumer Secret>";

        string oauth_token_secret =
            "<token secret>";

        string signingKey =
            Uri.EscapeDataString(consumerSecret) + "&" +
            Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_token_secret);

        //GS - Sign the request
        HMACSHA1 hasher = new HMACSHA1(
            new ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes(signingKey));

        string signatureString = Convert.ToBase64String(
            hasher.ComputeHash(
            new ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes(baseString)));

        return signatureString;
    }

public ActionResult AccessToken()
    {            
        //GS - Get the oAuth params
        string status = "Hello Ladies + Gentlemen, a signed OAuth request!";
        string postBody = "status=" +
            Uri.EscapeDataString(status);

        string oauth_consumer_key = "bidjtABOkF0b3mvw1UaHWDf7x";
        string oauth_nonce = Convert.ToBase64String(
            new ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes(
                DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString()));

        string oauth_signature_method = "HMAC-SHA1";
        string oauth_token =
            "84473240-brz5BNw9r2WfbufzJ2WjaLysCBHmJjhjJxMVGz8Od";

        string callbackURL = Uri.EscapeDataString("http://localhost:37808/");

        TimeSpan ts = DateTime.UtcNow -
            new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);

        string oauth_timestamp =
            Convert.ToInt64(ts.TotalSeconds).ToString();

        string oauth_version = "1.0";

        string sSig = signedSignature(status, postBody, oauth_consumer_key, oauth_nonce, oauth_signature_method, oauth_token, 
                                    callbackURL, oauth_timestamp, oauth_version);

        //GS - Tell Twitter we don't do the 100 continue thing
        ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;

        //GS - Instantiate a web request and populate the 
        //authorization header
        HttpWebRequest hwr =
            (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(
            @"https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token");

        string authorizationHeaderParams = String.Empty;
        authorizationHeaderParams += "OAuth ";
        authorizationHeaderParams += "oauth_nonce=" + "\"" +
            Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_nonce) + "\",";

        authorizationHeaderParams +=
            "oauth_signature_method=" + "\"" +
            Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_signature_method) +
            "\",";
        authorizationHeaderParams += "oauth_callback=" + "\"" +
            callbackURL + "\",";

        authorizationHeaderParams += "oauth_timestamp=" + "\"" +
            Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_timestamp) + "\",";

        authorizationHeaderParams += "oauth_consumer_key="
            + "\"" + Uri.EscapeDataString(
            oauth_consumer_key) + "\",";

        authorizationHeaderParams += "oauth_signature=" + "\""
            + Uri.EscapeDataString(sSig) + "\",";

        authorizationHeaderParams += "oauth_version=" + "\"" +
            Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_version) + "\"";

        hwr.Headers.Add(
            "Authorization", authorizationHeaderParams);

        //GS - POST off the request
        hwr.Method = "POST";
        hwr.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        Stream stream = hwr.GetRequestStream();
        byte[] bodyBytes =
            new ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes(postBody);

        stream.Write(bodyBytes, 0, bodyBytes.Length);
        stream.Flush();
        stream.Close();

        //GS - Allow us a reasonable timeout in case
        //Twitter's busy
        hwr.Timeout = 3 * 60 * 1000;

        try
        {
                HttpWebResponse rsp = hwr.GetResponse()
                    as HttpWebResponse;
            rsp.StatusCode.ToString();
                //GS - Do something with the return here...
        }
        catch (WebException e)
        {
            //GS - Do some clever error handling here...
        }

        return View();            
    }
```

I am not sure where exactly am going wrong. I have gone through the documents several times and cant seem to find out where I have gone wrong?

The error I get is `401 Unauthorized access`

Comment: Do you want to use your own solution or are you happy with using third party library that does this for you?

Comment: I can get it to work on third party libs however would rather like to see how the conventional oAuth works? More fun in that :)